# How can I line up the dropdown menu?

Tags: css

The dropdown menu is not aligning properly. The dropdown options are to the right for some reason instead of aligned ('students', 'programs', 'trainings').
Here is the css code for the menu:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 #drop-nav {
 width: 1000px;
 }
 ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
overflow: visible;
position: static;
}
ul li {
border: 1px solid #000000;
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
right: -4px;
background-color: white;
}
li ul {
display: none;
background-color: #3333ff;
}
ul li a {
padding: 10px 18px 5px 90px;
background: #3333ff none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #ffffff;
overflow: visible;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
ul li a:hover {
background: #3366ff none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
overflow: visible;
}
li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
}
li:hover li {
float: none;
background-color: #3366ff;
}
li:hover a {
background: #2346b1 none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
}
li:hover li a:hover {
background: #40a3f6 none repeat scroll 0% 50%;
}
#drop-nav li ul li {
border-top: 0px none;
overflow: visible;
visibility: visible;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
text-align: justify;
clear: none;
display: table-row;
width: 140px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the html:

```
<ul id="drop-nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="students.html">Students</a></li>
  <li><a href="programs.html">Programs</a></li>
  <li><a href="trainings.html">Trainings</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
 <li><a href="services.html">Services Offered</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="products.html">Our Products</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly so we can read it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because ou are using padding-left at 90px. You can change it to this:

```
ul li ul li a {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 18px 5px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pyrzvkte/19/)

Comment: The only thing is the menu becomes smaller when I change the padding. I would like it to go across the whole page..

Comment: What do you mean the whole page?

Comment: It looks great on fiddle, but for some reason when I try it in the kompozer editing program the text still moves..

Comment: I made and other fixes in css. Take a better look i add comments in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are referring to but the text is affected as you have too much left padding on the anchor links compared the other sides.

```
 ul li a {
     padding: 10px 18px 5px 90px; /* 90px!!! */
```

Try something less

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9b7vy24/2/)